# Abort(404) makes my Cookie::get('...') to a random hash instead of what it's supposed to be

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

When I abort 404 with laravel, or when it 404's by itself, my Cookie::get('department') transform itself from:

> "Oslo"

to

> "eyJpdiI6IjdOaDJSZ29jWXd2OHhmbzVNNHNBemc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYmdoOVdWN2RFRUdjNlhEa2w4cUl1Zz09IiwibWFjIjoiM2NiNWRhOGIyNWMzYzg4Mzc2ZTM2YmZlNTFkNmY4MWZkNGM3ODE3ZmJhMDhkZWRmNGY1ZDgxNDMzYjhmYmY1NyJ9 ◀eyJpdiI6IjdOaDJSZ29jWXd2OHhmbzVNNHNBemc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYmdoOVdWN2RFRUdjNlhEa2w4cUl1Zz09IiwibWFjIjoiM2NiNWRhOGIyNWMzYzg4Mzc2ZTM2YmZlNTFkNmY4MWZkNGM3ODE3ZmJhMDhk ▶"

It works on all other pages.

Since I use cookies to get the right contactinfo for the chosen department, it can't find that long string (where it's supposed to be "Oslo") in my database I get an error every time the page 404's

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Laravel uses the [EncryptCookie middleware](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php) per default on all your requests. You can specify the cookies that should not be encrypted in the `$except` property of the middleware:

```
class EncryptCookies extends Middleware
{
    protected $except = [
        'department'
    ];
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. It works now, I would kiss you if I could

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Don't forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: The answer provided by Bas K should be the accepted answer, as this solution introduces a security issue.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer has a security risk because you just disabling encryption on the cookies which you may not want.

The real cause is that the 404 page is not a page in the web routes.
There for the middleware list `web` is not used.

if you want to use encrypted cookies on the 404 page you need to add `\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,` to the global middleware list in `kernel.php`

app/Http/Kernel.php:

```
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
   \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class, // ADD THIS LINE
];
```